# Sampling in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with roughly equal Voronoi cells

Tags: sampling, monte-carlo, random-generation

N random points in a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ induce a
[Voronoi splitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)
or [tessellation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation).
Is there a way of random-generating points
so that the volumes of the Voronoi cells are roughly equal ?

This is 3 related questions, for $L_1, L_2$ and $L_\inf$ norms
(in 3d, random splits of an octahedron, sphere, cube).

(Where does this come from ?
In searching for a minimum of a noisy function of $n$ variables,
one may start N parallel searches from N random start points,
e.g. 10 start points in 5d.
Small Voronoi cells are then inefficient,
equal-sized cells most efficient.)

Comment: Not my area, but are [low-discrepancy sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence) any use?

Comment: You need to stipulate something about the boundaries of the domain, because *always* there will be unbounded cells of infinite area in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Also--at least in the $L_2$ case--it is unclear that maximizing efficiency would be good for the algorithm. With $n$ large, the points would have to be *very* close to equally spaced, which might reduce the chances of being near a minimum.

Comment: @onestop That's a good guess, but there's a subtle twist: here, the OP appears to want a "low-discrepancy" set of points that (a) are conditioned to lie within some specified finite-volume region (for simple regions this is no problem) and (b) that have a *predetermined count* $N$ (equal to the number of processors): this is the subtle part.

Comment: @whuber, yes finite volume: octahedron, sphere, cube; and smallish N n, e.g. 10 points in R5 -- the general case is surely difficult. Monte-Carlo people seem to often take just Uniform(0,1) i.i.d points in a cube; could a U-shaped distribution be better ?  Onestop: thanks, will look, but it's not clear to me how they equi-volume.

Comment: I really don't think you want to stop with just an equal-volume criterion, Denis. Look at the 2D case, for instance (it generalizes): pick $(r,\phi)$ so that $\phi$ is uniformly distributed on $[0, 2\pi/N)$ and set $x_i = (\cos(\phi+2\pi i/N), \sin(\phi+2\pi i/N))$, $i=0, 1, \ldots, N-1$. The Voronoi cells of $\{x_i\}$ within any disk concentric with the origin have *exactly* equal 2-volumes.  Depending on how $r$ is distributed, you might never start near the origin or you might never start near the boundary of the disk.  That sounds like poor behavior for a search algorithm.